# How can I add conditional predicates by given java boolean?

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I have a business method which should conditionally add a predicate.

```
public <T extends BaseEntity, Y> T findEntityByUniqueAttribute(
        final Class<T> entityType,
        final Supplier<SingularAttribute<? super T, Y>> attributeSupplier,
        final Supplier<? extends Y> valueSupplier,
        final boolean filterDeleted) {
    return applyWithPersistenceContext(manager -> {
        final CriteriaBuilder builder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        final CriteriaQuery<T> criteria
                = builder.createQuery(entityType);
        final Root<T> from = criteria.from(entityType);
        criteria.select(from);
        criteria.where(builder.equal(from.get(attributeSupplier.get()),
                                     valueSupplier.get()));
        final TypedQuery<T> query = manager.createQuery(criteria);
        try {
            return Optional.of(query.getSingleResult())
                    .filter(result -> !filterDeleted
                                      || result.getDeleted() != null)
                    .orElse(null);
        } catch (final NoResultException nre) {
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see this method does fetch and check.
Now I believe I can improve this by adding the post filter(`!filterDeleted || result.getDeleted() != null`) into the query itself.

How can I do it?

So far, I did this.

```
        final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>(2);
        predicates.add(builder.equal(from.get(attributeSupplier.get()),
                                     valueSupplier.get()));
        if (filterDeleted) {
            predicates.add(builder.isNull(from.get(BaseEntity_.deleted)));
        }
        criteria.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        final TypedQuery<T> query = manager.createQuery(criteria);
        try {
            return query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (final NoResultException nre) {
            return null;
        }
```

Is there any way to make a `Predicate` with given `filterDeleted`?

Comment: why are you doing the equivalent of "deleted == null" ? Better chance of success with "deleted == false"

Comment: @NeilStockton my `deleted`'s type is `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: so what is the BOOLEAN that you talk about? That is what needs comparing with FALSE. If you had put your (abbreviated) classes this would have been clearer.

Comment: if the input parameter is your BOOLEAN that is being referred to, then generate your PREDICATE based on that and compare it with FALSE.

Comment: @NeilStockton That's it. How can I make a `Predicate` from the value of `filterDeleted`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the Predicate for a boolean parameter as being false like this

```
ParameterExpression<Boolean> param = builder.parameter(Boolean.class, "myParam");
Predicate paramFalse = builder.isFalse(param);
```

and then set the parameter as input to the query in the normal way.